# regex for content between and including the parenthees

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Can someone help me with a regex that will catch  the following:

- has to be at the end of the string
- remove all characters between  ( and ) including the parentheses

It's going to me done in javascript.

here's what i have so far -

```
var title = $(this).find('title').text().replace(/\w+\s+\(.*?\)/, "");
```

It seems to be catching some chars outside of the parenthees though.

Comment: Possibly nested parens? If so, forget it. Regex can't possibly parse nested delimiters.

Comment: In a separate regex, i also need to be able to remove   the  < and > characters.

Comment: no nested parentheses.    Something to catch this - Ice Hockey Tryouts (1/6/2011 - 1/7/2011)

Comment: @delnan Regex can parse nested in the better PCRE flavours, Javascript bit trickier, needs a small plugin.

Comment: @Orbling: But those aren't quite **regular** expressions ;)

Comment: @delnan: None of the main languages use **regular** expressions, they all have PCRE implementations these days, have done for many years.  They are still called regexp, people do not seem able to adapt to this.

Answer (score 1):

This deals with matching between parens, and only at the of the string:  `\([^(]*\)\s*$`.  If the parens might be nested, you need a parser, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
var title = $(this).find('title').text().replace(/\([^()]*\)\s*$/, "");
```

should work.

To remove `<` and `>` you don't really need regexes, but of course you can do a `mystr.replace(/[<>]+/g, "");`

This will match a `(`, any number of characters except parentheses (thereby ensuring that only the last parentheses will match) and a `)`, and then the end of the string.

Currently, it allows whitespace between the parentheses and the end of the string (and will remove it, too). If that's not desired, remove the `\s*` bit from the regex.

Comment: thanks tim, can u help me with one more? In a separate regex, i also need to be able to remove the < and > character, I don't need to remove the chars between.

Comment: 3:00 PM - 4:00 PM<  It doesn't seem to catch the trailing symbol  <  mystr.replace(/[<>]+/, "");

Comment: It leaves one stray <  behind unless I rerun the regex. Not sure why the first one doesn't catch all instances.

Answer (score 0):

Where's the `$`?  You need a dollar at the end and possibly catch optional whitespace.

```
var title = $(this).find('title').text().replace(/\s*\([^\)]*?\)\s*$/, "");
```

If brackets can also be angle brackets, then this can match those too:

```
var title = $(this).find('title').text().replace(/\s*(\([^\)]*?\)|\<[^\>]*?\>)\s*$/, "");
```

Comment: This will still match from the first to the last parenthesis in the entire string, not just the last pair. Remember the leftmost-longest rule - the lazy quantifier doesn't make any difference in this case.